# 8 GB of physical RAM shows up as "7.00 GB installed (3.99 usable)" in Win7Pro 64-bit's System applet

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I realize there are many questions out there similar to this, but the standard answers of "you're on 32-bit" and "it's reserved for graphics" don't seem to apply.  I'm not sure how to verify the latter because I'm not on-site with access to the BIOS, but 3 GB seems quite steep for graphics reservation.  Also according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610 we should have a 192 GB limit on this box, since it's 64-bit Win7 Pro.  Yet we get less than half of the 8 GB physical showing up as usable.  In Resource Monitor, it says 3081MB are hardware reserved.  How can I reduce this, or at least find out which hardware is reserving it?

Also I have an NVIDIA QuadroFX 580, so it shouldn't use any system RAM.

Comment: Have you confirmed each module is working by itself?

Comment: @Ramhound, No, I haven't yet but I could next time I'm on-site.  But wouldn't that make it say "3.99 installed"?  I thought when a module fails it fails entirely, not losing 1/4 of its capacity, and "hardware reserving" the other 3/4.

Comment: The fact its saying 7GB installed and not 8GB itself is odd. More information about the hardware might be nice.  The fact you are able to use 3.99GB tells me you actually do have a 64-bit Windows operating system installed because if it was 32-bit you wouldn't even be able ( out of the box ) use that amount.  It would be closer to 3.25GB-3.50GB.

Comment: I sadly have the same issue too, Win7 x64, where my 4GB are showing 1.99GB usable. Apparently many have found the "Memory Remap" feature in the BIOS to be the culprate. This wasn't the case for me, but worth taking a check if you can manage to get access to the BIOS http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-197079-total-installed-ram-not-usable

Comment: I can provide more information about the hardware, what are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @root, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that too.  I take it you are still without a solution in your case?

Comment: What's the make and model? Some devices simply can't support that much RAM. How old is this device?

Comment: My Lenovo R60 only shows 3GB no matter how much RAM's in it... so BIOS limitations on usable RAM are very real.

Comment: @MDTGuy, it's an off-lease we purchased in the last couple months, so not that old: Lenovo ThinkStation S20.  And I don't know why they'd make a model that supports 8 GB without the BIOS to use it...if that's how it is, that's extremely unfortunate.

Comment: @root, There's no memory map option in the BIOS.

Comment: OK, reseating the RAM now shows 6 GB available and nothing about "usable".  But I think we were duped, our local shop sold us a supposed 8 GB system and there are only 7 GB in there.  Which, it seems, according to the docs, may be the cause of a missing GB, because it needs to be evenly mirrored between the two CPUs to work properly.

Comment: @Ramhound maybe you could add your comment as an actual answer so I can accept it...

Comment: Model Supports up to 24GB. Run a memory test?

Comment: @Kev - Verify the labels on the modules each one should be 2GB.  My comment is already an answer to other questions already.  Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @Ramhound...re: answer, if you say so.  The modules actually are 1x 2GB, 1x 1GB, and 2x 9xxMB.  We're missing a 1GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reseat the RAM, and per the docs for that model of computer, you need matching/symmetrical RAM modules.